# reload page to reflect changes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've my jquery code

```
.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "crop/crop.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function(data){
                $('#popupMargin').hide();
                $('#avatar img').remove();
                $('#avatar').load('crop/dp.php');
                //$('#avatar').hide();

            }
        });
```

Now

```
//Codes in the file loaded (`dp.php`) called by jQuery above

    <?php session_start(); ?>
    <!-- To display display picture just after croppping -->
    <img src="users/<?php echo $_SESSION['userId']; ?>/img/dp.jpg" width="150">
```

The above ajax is called whenever I clicked a button `#btn`. The file `crop.php` crops an image and saves it at the same location and same name as seen above in the `dp.php`.

So it means, everytime the user clicks on the button `#btn`, the image is changed. I want the change to be reflected  as `$('#avatar').load('crop/dp.php');` is called in the jQuery code above; however, I'm not sure if it's some kind of caching that the old image still shows up.

Does `.load()` reloads the page? How do I make sure that the change (updated image) is shown instead of the old one??

Comment: try `var_dump` of the `$_SESSION` variable to make sure it changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're worried about caching, you can append a timestamp as a GET parameter to your ajax request. Which will normally force the browser to download a fresh copy.

```
 $('#avatar').load('crop/dp.php?' + (new Date().getTime()));
```

Also, if the $_SESSION['userId'] remains the same between requests, it wouldn't hurt to force a reload of the actual jpg too.

```
<img src="users/<?php echo $_SESSION['userId']; ?>/img/dp.jpg?<?php echo time(); ?>" width="150">
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend appending:

```
'?foo='+Math.random();
```

to your image path.. its a good hack for making sure you always see the most recent version of a file (e.g. by providing the url with a different parameter each time - you are guaranteed to circumvent any caching).

Comment: Can't I just reload the image with the same path?? Reload through ajax

Answer (score 0):

Try `var_dump` of the `$_SESSION` variable to make sure it changed in your PHP code.

Make sure in both `crop/crop.php` and `crop/dp.php` you have `session_start()` at the top of the code.

Comment: The session variable is static.. doesn't have anything to do. You can assume the the path to the image as `users/10/img/dp.jpg`. So the next time someone clicks the #btn, it rewrites the image file with a new one. And then, through my jquery, I'm calling `$('#avatar').load('crop/dp.php`. and Im expecting that the new image is shown when `.load()` loads the `dp.php`